# Is is possible to format an Applescript dialog?

Tags: applescript

I am writing an AppleScript and I'd like to be able to format text in a `display dialog` box. For instance, I want part of the text to be bold or italic. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't beleive you can from what I remember, but I'd need to check hence comment (not an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Barring using Cocoa dialogs and integrating them into your script (*way* out of the scope of this question – and of my expertise, too), you can’t. AppleScript’s `display dialog` does not allow for typographic formatting (and neither does the only script friendly alternative to AppleScript’s inbuilt abilities, Carsten Blüm’s [Pashua](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/pashua/)).

If all you need is for the first (supposedly most important) part of the text to be emphasized, you can use `display alert` instead of `display dialog`

```
display alert "this is the important part" message "… and this is not"
```

which will give you this:

[image: display alert example]

Comment: Will `display alert` allow you to have a text input?

Comment: @daviesgeek: nope. It’s strictly a message type dialog.

Comment: Too bad. I need a text input box. :-(